# Pandas DataFrame.write_parquet() and setting the Zstd compression level

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, zstd

I am writing out a compressed Parquet file from `DataFrame` as following:

```py
result_df.to_parquet("my-data.parquet", compression="zstd")
```

How can I instruct Pandas on the compression level of zstd coding?

Comment: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.write_table.html#pyarrow.parquet.write_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `pyarrow` engine you can send `compression_level` in `kwargs` to `to_parquet`

```
result_df.to_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow', compression='zstd', compression_level=1)
```

Test:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

path = 'my-data.parquet'
result_df = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(100000)})

for i in range(10):

    # create the file
    result_df.to_parquet(path, engine='pyarrow', compression='zstd', compression_level=i)

    # get compressed file size
    metadata = pq.ParquetFile(path).metadata.row_group(0).column(0)
    print(f'compression level {i}: {metadata.total_compressed_size}')
```

Output:

```
compression level 0: 346166
compression level 1: 309501
compression level 2: 309500
compression level 3: 346166
compression level 4: 355549
compression level 5: 381823
compression level 6: 310104
compression level 7: 310088
compression level 8: 308866
compression level 9: 308866
```

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>pandas 2.1.0</kbd>
<kbd>pyarrow 13.0.0</kbd>
<kbd>fastparquet 2023.8.0</kbd>

### How to set compression level in DataFrame.to_parquet

In Pandas 2.1.0, we can use [two different libraries as engines](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) to write parquet files - [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/) and [fastparquet](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). They have different ways to address a compression level, which are generally incompatible. So in both cases, it is better to explicitly specify the value of the `engine` parameter in order to avoid any confusion.

#### engine = 'pyarrow'

In case of **pyarrow**, which is a default option in pandas 2.1.0, we have to pass to the engine the `compression_level` parameter, which is described in the [pyarrow documentation](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetWriter.html#pyarrow-parquet-parquetwriter):

> **compression_level** : `int` or `dict`, default `None`
> Specify the compression level for a codec, either on a general basis or per-column. If None is passed, arrow selects the compression level for the compression codec in use. The compression level has a different meaning for each codec, so you have to read the documentation of the codec you are using. An exception is thrown if the compression codec does not allow specifying a compression level.

This parameter will be passed to the pyarrow parquet writer as an item of the  `kwargs` dict of the [to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/2.1.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html#pandas-dataframe-to-parquet) method.

#### engine = 'fastparquet'

In case of **fastparquet**, the compression level is passed as a part of the `compression` parameter, which in this case should look like

```
{
  column_name: {
    'type': desired_compression_for_specified_column, 
    'args': kwargs_for_specified_compression_type
  },
  # ...
  '_default': {    # default compression type for non-specified columns
    'type': 'zstd',
    'args': {'level': desired_compression_level_for_zstandard}
  }
}
```

Note that there's no `compression_level` parameter in the [fastparquet.write](https://fastparquet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#fastparquet.write) method, so we can't use it as a parameter in pandas `DataFrame.to_parquet` with `fastparquet` as an engine. As of possible keywords in the `'args'` dictionary fot Zstandard compression, see details of [cramjam.zstd.compress](https://docs.rs/cramjam/latest/cramjam/zstd/fn.compress.html), which is [used underneath of fastparquet](https://github.com/dask/fastparquet/blob/df1219300a96bc1baf9ebad85f4f5676a130c9e8/fastparquet/compression.py#L60) version 2023.8.0.

#### Sample code

```
my_compression_level = 2

# with pyarrow
df.to_parquet(
    'my-data.parquet', 
    engine='pyarrow', 
    compression='zstd', 
    compression_level=my_compression_level
)

# with fastparquet
df.to_parquet(
    'my-data.parquet', 
    engine='fastparquet', 
    compression={
        '_default': {
            'type': 'zstd', 
            'args': {'level': my_compression_level}
        }
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, using the `compression_opts` parameter in the `to_parquet` function is preferable as it allows for defining compression options through a dictionary and the `compression_level` key specifically determines the compression level for zstd coding,so adjusting its value allows for balancing compression ratio and speed, with higher values yielding better compression but slower performance.The default value is 3.

```
result_df.to_parquet("my-data.parquet", compression="zstd", compression_opts={'compression_level': 10})
```

and this is a simple example for that:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'B': ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux', 'quux']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

#writing DataFrame to Parquet with zstd compression and compression level
df.to_parquet("my-data.parquet", compression="zstd", compression_opts={'compression_level': 10})
```

Comment: Can you please explain how and when this is supposed to work? I'd appreciate if you could provide references to where `compression_opts` is described.

Comment: @Vitalizzare https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/dataset.html

Comment: How's it connected with `pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet`?